# Complex left join sql

Tags: sql

I am trying to make a report for salaries of a company and I want to show all the employees of the company by using some query like this:

```
select tab1.name
      ,tab1.job
      ,tab1.salary
      ,tab2.discount-days
      ,(tab1.salary-((tab1.salary/30)*tab2.discount-days) as 'total' 
from tab1 
    left join tab2 
      on tab1.PK = tab2.FK 
     and tab2.date between '01/09/2014' and '30/09/2014';
```

Here it shows all the employees and that have taken discounts but the period condition does not work  as it show all the discounts that have been given to the employee

Please need help to make the query to work well with the period condition

Comment: In normal SQL, `tab2.discount-days` will be treated as an expression subtracting `days` from `tab2.discount`.  Is that dash an underscore?  If you have multiple entries between the two given dates for a given employee, you will get multiple entries in the output.  If you don't want that, perhaps you need to apply an aggregate (SUM?) and a GROUP BY clause.

Answer (score 0):

That is because you mention your pridicate in ON statement and that is make difference in left or right joins.
Mentiob your pridicate in where clause.

Comment: Actually, that part looks correct.  Yes, it's true that the syntax `Table1 LEFT JOIN Table2 ON <conditions>` means that the `<condiitons>` can only constrain the results from Table2, and never the results from Talbe1, but the discount period is *in* Table2 in this case so that is correct. (moving it to the `WHERE` clause would effectively turn it into an `INNER JOIN`.)

Comment: but when t run it shows all the discounts that an employee had taken not the discount in the period only